# Live webcam recording in iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, safari, webcam, rtmp

As far as I can tell there is no way to do this, but I wanted to ask the community to be certain.

I want to record live webcam and save to the server in **Safari mobile** for **iOS6/7**

This is not a web app, so the method below doesn't work, just invokes the standard file upload, not the camera capture:

http://longhandpixels.net/demos/mobilesafari-ios6/

Flash, not supported

getUserMedia, not supported on iOS

I can't think of any way to do this without using an app, does anyone have any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: how do you want to pass the web server ? frame by frame ? a recorder video ?

Comment: anyway that you know is possible I would be interested to look at @Basheer_CAD